# Symfony4: No route found for "GET /lucky/number"

Tags: php, symfony, controller, symfony-routing, symfony4

I am starting to play with symfony4. I've just created new application and create new LuckyController. It works with routes.yaml configured in this manner:

```
lucky:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

With the following controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController
{
    public function number()
    {
        return new Response('<html><head></head><body>' . rand(111, 999) . '</body></html>');
    }
}
```

But I want to use annotations. So I decided to comment routes.yaml. Following documentation that explain how to [create a route in symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#creating-routes) I've made this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class LuckyController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function number()
    {
        return new Response('<html><head></head><body>' . rand(111, 999) . '</body></html>');
    }
}
```

[image: No route found]

Comment: Have you run `composer require annotations`?

Comment: I've read just now http://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html#auto-installing-recipes-with-symfony-flex

Comment: Aaaaaaand. It works!

Comment: Same problem..   Not working though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Symfony4 you have to install `annotations` bundle.

Run this command `composer require annotations`

Then restart Your project.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP, except running the command "composer require annotations" doesn't solve the issue :/ Exact same error.

Comment: @MégaLag, Have restart your project or web server apache?

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev Is it possible that some other changes are needed? I've the exact same problem as OP and doing what you suggested didn't help. Even after restarting everything.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, this solution is mentioned docs (https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html) as well. But it is not working. The exception is thrown from the file vendor\symfony\http-kernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php, where there is no mention about annotations.

Comment: But this is not mentioned here https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html which it definitelly should be. Just doing by the documantion and you are getting error.

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes this problem occurs because of cache.you need to run `php bin/console cache:clear`.then it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing when trying the annotations, then I found out with the demo installed (the blog) you need to add the language in the URL. So the documentation says:

> http://localhost:8000/lucky/number will work exactly like before

That did not work. This however did:

```
http://localhost:8000/en/lucky/number
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in @Jack70 answer.

https://127.0.0.1:8000/en/random/number

This should work.

If you run the command `php bin/console debug:router` it would show you the list of routes available as you can see in that list, you need to add the locale (language) as first argument.

`app_annotationsample_number   ANY        ANY      ANY    /{_locale}/random/number`

Answer (score 0):

If you use annotations - you need check **config/routes/anotations.yaml**.
You need check path to your controller or add new path, for example:

```
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you'll get that error if the route name appears more than once.

I ran into that error while developing Angular app, so in order to debug I tried that same route in Postman, which I knew used to work fine, but this time it did not throwing the mentioned error. Luckily, I have just added one new controller, so finding the culprit was easy: the problem was that after copying methods from web controller to api controller I forgot to change route name in one of the methods.
So you might wanna be careful when copying :)